# Calling a PHP Function into sql query

Tags: php, sql, function

I have a MySQL table called "invoice_prod" :

```
id | qte | price | id_tva
```

And another table called "tva" :

```
id_tva | content
```

Now, I want to find the total of an invoice, so I made this query and it works.

```
$sql_mnt = mysql_query("
    SELECT SUM( (qte * price) * ( 1 + (tva / 100))) AS total_un_prod
    FROM invoice_prod 
    WHERE id='$id_invoice'
    ");
```

I have just one problem with this query. The "tva" return the "id of the tva" and not its content. Which I have to extract its content from the table "tva".

Clearly, this query return this value of the tva : "1", or, it should return "18%" which is the content of the tva's ID.

I tried to make a PHP function that extracts the tva's content from an id and include it into the SQL query like this :

```
$sql_mnt = mysql_query("
    SELECT SUM(( qte * price) * ( 1 + (" .
    tva_get_by_id(tva) . "/ 100))) AS total_un_prod
    FROM invoice_prod 
    WHRE id='$id_invoice'
    ");
```

But it doesn't work.

What should I do ?

Thanks a lot for your help and have a nice day :)

Comment: You desperately need to understand that SQL query is just a **string** of text, being sent to the SQL server. And SQL server do not understand PHP, but SQL only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
$sql_mnt = mysql_query("
         SELECT SUM((`qte`*`price`)*(1+(`content`/100))) AS `total_un_prod`
         FROM `invoice_prod`
         LEFT JOIN `tva` USING (`id_tva`)
         WHERE `id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($id_invoice)."'");
```

this connects the two tables within mysql, so you can use the `content` field directly, which I presume holds the TVA percentage.

**edit** formatted and addressed the escaping of `id_invoice` as well (I guess it is int so a cast would suffice, but if not, this will work as well)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

I tried your solution but I got this error message :

Unknown column 'id_tva' in 'from clause'.

The column "id_tva" exists in the table "tva".

Comment: I find the solution :)

I just delete "using...." and replace it by "on invoice_prod.tva = tva.id_tva".

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: good to hear, but in your question you really state that both tables have a `id_tva` field ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand correctly what you're doing here, but it looks like what you want is an INNER JOIN on the tva table, and then use tva.content in your calculation. Is that correct?